# c# winform custom button text can't show full when too long

Tags: c#, winforms

How display a mutli-line text on a WinForms custom button? If my text is too long it is shown like this:

[image: button image]

but I'd like it to be wrapped on multiple lines.

Is it any property need to set ?

```
Button b1 = new Button();
b1.Text = myReader.GetString(1);  
b1.Click += b1_Click;
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b1);  
flowLayoutPanel1.GetFlowBreak(b1);
```

Comment: you can set a newline if you want. `b1.Text = myReader.GetString(1) + Environment.NewLine + "next line";`

Comment: Also you can check if string is longer than button with `TextRenderer.MeasureText();`

Comment: I just tried it with a normal `Windows.Forms.Button` with default settings and it wraps the text on multiple lines by default. What kind of "custom" button do you use?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Don't know what I'm missing... my `Windows.Forms.Button`s do it by default.

Comment: @RenéVogt Wait ... of course, don't know what I confused that with. You are right.

Comment: What .NET Framework are you using? Maybe the behaviour changed with the version. I'm using .NET 4.5 and (as already said) my buttons wrap the text automatically, no special property needed (didn't even find a way to _not_ wrap).

Comment: @RenéVogt The behavior in .Net 4.5 and.Net 2.0 is the same. The only case which I could reproduce the problem is by setting padding top and bottom large enough to make the button show only a single line and set autoellipsis to true.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one my lad:

```
        b1.AutoSize = true;
        b1.Text = "Multiline text " + Environment.NewLine + "on a button";
```